# Audio Recorder Not Recording From Analog OutPut / Firefox

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Records only from USB mic. Not from audio output? No help to check pavucontrol/recording. There it is... audio-recorder but not recording anything. Some months ago I messed with speechsynthesis. Perhaps it messed all soundsystem. Reinstalled pulse, alsa no help.
Xubuntu 20.04. Pavucontrol muteboxes not showing? Alsamix all unmuted...

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details. Why would you expect to record audio *output*? What *exactly* have you done so far? Telling us that you "messed with" something doesn't tell us what you actually did.  So that other people can understand your details, write to the best of your ability. For example, if you don't write in complete sentences, it can be very hard to understand what you are trying to say. Help us help you and make sure your details are clear and easy to understand.

Comment: I have used audio-recorder to record firefox sound, audio output before it got "the sound system" messed. I cannot remember what or don't know if installing speech synthesis software broke somehow normal alsa -pulseaudio. That some other cases suggested pavucontrol recordtab check have not helped.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wanted to record the audio from training videos played via the Firefox browser, so I could add the audio to the screen cast video recordings of the same training videos with added notes of my own for better understanding of concepts using Kdenlive. So for the audio recorder software, I opted to use the sound recording tool from the link https://vitux.com/how-to-record-audio-in-ubuntu/

I found this to work perfectly with added features like being able to set a predetermined start recording time and period which was useful allowing me to start an audio recording a few seconds before I started playing the training video, giving a period of silence to ease editing later. You can also start the audio recording manually before the audio is active.

There is no "missing the first bit of audio" as I experienced when using Audacity, also the auto pause and restart when a silent period is detected, creating the missing initial audio being missed by Audacity. There are no problems with audio output recordings when selecting between the HDMI to monitor/speakers or earphones outputs either.

I've installed on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a 64 bit AMD processor and can confirm recordings from output to connected earphones worked perfectly. Remember to select the correct "Source" of Audio output option to record, the default option was not the correct in my case.